# Source field in DRF serializer with multiple foreign keys to the same model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=MgrToTeam, related_name='mng')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=UsrToTeam,related_name='usr')
```

I now have a serializer where i need to display all the users and managers associated with a team:

```
class TeamDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

managers = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
users = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='name')

class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'managers', 'users']
```

However, this gives me the same output for both the users and managers.How do i fix this ?

Comment: Shouldn't your `users` field in the serializer use a queryset of `User` instead of `Team`?

Comment: Typo..fixed now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious as to why you want to use a `SlugRelatedField`. Assuming you do have a `UserSerializer` of some sort, would it work for you to do it like this?

```py
class TeamDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    managers = UserSerializer(many=True)
    users = UserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'managers', 'users']
```

Comment: Even a nested serializer is fine but how do I differentiate between a user and a manager..

Comment: @Amistad I'd be inclined to think this should actually be a flag in the `User` model (be it through some permissions system or just a boolean field, e.g. `is_manager`), unless you actually have different models for users who are managers and those who aren't.

Comment: As you can see there is an through table for the M2M keys which keeps a tab of who is a user and who is a manager ..two separate tables to do this..

Comment: @Amistad Then it's up to you in the `UserSerializer` to extract that data and return it in the `user` object as a field (using `serializers.SerializerMethodField`, for instance).

Comment: @Amistad, the differentiation between the two user types in defined in your `Team` model, that's sufficient.

Comment: @Amistad Please mark one of the answers as the correct answer, if one of them solved your issue. If not, feel free to share what else is missing :)

Comment: @EndreBoth...i just tested it now and it works..Looks like DRF automatically will look for M2M fields

Answer (score 0):

**if you just want Just primary key as below**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "helo",
        "users": [
            1,
            2
        ],
        "managers":[
        1,
        2,
        ]
    }
]
```

```py
class TeamDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'users','managers']
```

**if you want return object properties as below**

```py
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "helo",
        "users": [
            {
                "email": "admin@gmail.com",
                "first_name": ""
            },
            {
                "email": "admin1@gmail.com",
                "first_name": ""
            }
        ],
        "managers": [
            {
                "email": "admin@gmail.com",
                "first_name": ""
            },
            {
                "email": "admin1@gmail.com",
                "first_name": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```py
class TeamDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserDetailSerializer(many=True)
    managers = UserDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'users', 'managers']
```

Comment: The problem is that managers and users are different since I store them in 2 separate tables using m2m relationship via through table..this gives me the same output for both of them which is not correct

Comment: please your other models here